# Doctrine EM - How to insert into a column

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I have with doctrine 2 entities: Club and User. In the User entitie i created a manytomany table:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Club", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sms_followers")
 **/
 private $smsfollower;
```

Now i wanne add data to the table. I use this:

```
//Get the club (no error handling created
$getclub = $this->em->getRepository('Club')->findOneBy(array('id' => $clubid));

//Get the user by login ID
$getuser = $this->em->getRepository('User')->findOneBy(array('id' => '7'));

//Insert the userID and ClubID to the table sms_followers
$getuser = $getclub->addSmsfollower();
```

I cant get this done... Anyone who can help me out?

Please keep the english as easy as possible, im from the netherlands

Answer (score 0):

What you most likely want is to add an SmsFollower to the collection you already have.

```php
// in your User enitity
public function addClub(Club $club)
{
    $this->clubs->add($club);
}

// in your Club entity
public function addSmsFollower(User $user)
{
    $this->sms_followers->add($user);
}
```

Then in your entity manager you can persist the objects and then flush to save them.

Tip: I named the fields sms_followers and clubs (plural, meervoud) because it's a many to many relationship.

Comment: Do you have a example for me please?

Comment: In your case it would be: $getclub->addSmsfollower($getuser); $this->em->persist($getclub); $this->em->flush(); You should read up on the Doctrine2 documentation regarding this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities

Comment: How can i retrieve the data from that table? Ive done it 2 times correctly, but cant get it done for the third time :S